# Does the assert() in assert.h in the C standard library support some sort of failed assertion handler?

Tags: c, assert, libc

Normally when you call `assert(foo())` and the assertion fails, the program automatically aborts. Is there any way to add some sort of handler that can clean up some resources before exiting?

Comment: You can add a signal handler for `SIGABRT`.

Comment: IF the code is on UNIX/Linux, yes, good answer +1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can handle the `SIGABRT` signal and do cleaning. Of course assert is just for debugging the application, so it is better to just fix the problem causing the failure instead of writing code to gracefully fail.

Comment: A good strategy, but you can also just define your own `assert` macro.

Comment: yes that's another option but then, it is not the assert() in assert.h :)

Comment: Well the thing is even though it is just debugging, not cleaning stuff up screws up my filesystem (of course I'm doing all this in `/tmp`!).

Answer (score 0):

The whole point of assert is to dump `__FILE__` and `__LINE__` information and call abort() immediately.  If you don't want to do that, roll your own error checking with a cleanup handler, or do as suggested in another answer and catch the abort() itself.  To your specific question, assert is just a macro, so you can't hook it directly.  For chapter and verse, see ISO C99, 7.2.1, p2.